# Change Value of Variable and return value using macros (c)

Tags: c

I am trying to use macros to change the value of a variable but also return a value in the process.

Essentially I want to convert the following function into a macro

```
if (a%2){
    even = 1
} else {
  even = 0
}

return even
```

I am struggling to do both in one go; the compiler kept returning me errors each time (returning/changing value).
Is there a way to do this using macros? Thank you so much! Note even is a variable already declared.

Comment: Try `(even = (((a) % 2) == 0))`. Please show the macro attempt.

Comment: The pseudo-code attempt posted sets `even = 1`  when `a` is odd.

Comment: or with a bang `(even = !((a) % 2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A macro definition corresponding to the code shown in the question is:

```
#define MyMacro(even, a) ((even) = (a)%2 ? 1 : 0)
```

The `? :` operator, used as `E1 ? E2 : E3,` selects its second (`E2`) or third (`E3`) operand according to whether the first operand (`E1`) evaluates as true (non-zero) or false (zero).

This macro produces an assignment expression, `even = something`. That “returns a value” as you request because an assignment expression can itself be used as a value. Its value is the value that is assigned.

Note that this macro sets `even` to be 1 if `a` is odd. If `even` is intended to describe the value of `a`, this contrasts with the sense of 1 versus 0 usually used. Normally, if a variable such as `even` is set to 1, it means something is even, and, if it is set to 0, it means the thing is not even. If you want to set `even` to 1 when `a` is even, you can use:

```
#define MyMacro(even, a) ((even) = (a)%2 ? 0 : 1)
```

That can also be written:

```
#define MyMacro(even, a) ((even) = !((a)%2)
```

because the `!` operator produces 1 if its operand is 0 and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Why would any expression % 2 produce anything but 0 or 1?

Comment: @Lundin: `-3 % 2` evaluates to −1.

Comment: Right... I'm too used at unsigned arithmetic. Anyway, an alternative would be `((a)%2==0)`. I don't think it will affect the amount of branches in the machine code though.

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
return (even = (a % 2) ? 1 : 0);
```

You should use the [ternary operator](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/c-ternary-operator/) in these kinds of situations.